# Count non-empty input field[]?

Tags: jquery, count, field, validation

With jQuery how do I count how many fields of my array field[] are not empty ?

Sample of the input field

```
<input type="file" name="arquivo[]" id="arquivo">
```

I was trying to make something up using map and get but it is not coming along well:

```
var total = 0;
var count = $('#arquivo[value!=""]').map(function() { total = total+1; }).get();
```

But no matter how many fields I have filled it always end up with the value of 1 and if I have no fields filled 0.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just find the `length` of the jQuery object, which returns the number of matched elements:

```
$('#arquivo[value!=""]').length
```

But you do know that this will *always* return `0` or `1`? The `id` property is *unique* to only one element, so you can't reuse it multiple times.

---

For example:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

When you run:

```
$('#foo').length;
```

It returns `1`, because only one element *should* exist with the `id` of `foo`.

---

Now try this:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

When you run:

```
$('.foo').length;
```

It returns `2`. Why? Because `class` can be reused many times.

---

What are you trying to do? Can you post a scenario with multiple input fields?

Comment: @Blender yours and mine only count 1 and not all fields from `arquivo[]`

Comment: We receive multiple images up to 10 and the first 3 are required.

Comment: You might be using the `id` attribute incorrectly. Can you post the HTML with the 10 images?

Comment: @Blender `arquivo[0], arquivo[1] ... arquivo[9]`

Comment: Okay. You can't have two elements with the same `id`. Ever. The maximum is one, which is what jQuery returns correctly. Try using `class` instead of `id` (see my example).

Comment: @Blender Thanks I have moved it from id to class `$('.arquivo[value!=""]').length;` and it counts just fine now.

Answer (score 3):

If you like to query and count by element name. You can use the below code

```
$('[name*=arquivo][value!=""]').length
```